# What does "Come on, let's wrangle up the cattle" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, speech, cinema

Andy said this to Woody in Toy Story 1. Is this idiom?

Comment: But this doesn't define an idiom. Did Woody literally have cattle that needed to be rounded/wrangled up, or did he seem to be speaking figuratively?  (More context would help.)

Comment: I haven't seen the movie since it originally came out, so don't recall the exact context.  But it either could have meant "let's get our collective asses in gear and get moving", or it could have simply been a random piece of "cowboy speak" such as Woody would have said when you (literally) pulled his string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[To wrangle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wrangle):

> - To manage or herd (horses or cattle).(AHD)
> - Meaning "take charge of horses" is by [1897](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wrangle&allowed_in_frame=0), American English.(Etymonline)

- to wrangle up: to drive/move the cattle together (into an enclosure, for instance).

[image]

Comment: The verb "to wrangle" has many other meanings. The first example of this one in the OED (sense 7) dates from 1899. If you know more about the origin of this usage I feel sure the OED would be interested in hearing from you. *1899   F. Remington Sundown Leflare 11   De herd, which was more horses..dan ten men kin wrangle.* Which language is this coming from?

Comment: @WS2 - the following extract seems to be from a 1893 magazine:  *"Many derivative words from horse — are all simple compounds. Besides horseback ... Horsify meant the witch's power to turn a man into a horse; horsing was supplying horses"*. ... ***The curious term,  horse-wrangler, is used in the West (America)*** ...https://books.google.it/books?hl=it&id=BN1IAAAAYAAJ&dq=wrangle+horses&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=horse-wrangler